# android layout: edittext shifting right and left

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I am working on a calculator where on the "screen" the left part shows the symbol + - * / and the right shows the digits. The size of the symbol cannot be too small, but when the user presses for the symbol and the symbol shows e.g. +, the figures on the right will shift rightwards a bit in order to accomodate the symbol.

The figure on the right keep shifting rightwards when have symbol while back to its place when no symbols. Also, the symbol cannot be shown properly. This is frustrating.

Yet I would like to maintain that the symbol and the figures be maintained within 1 row such that it really looks like calculator. How could this be handled? The layout code is as follows. Thanks in advance!!!!

[image]

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"  
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/symEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_span="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#003366"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ansEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_span="9"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:ems="4"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:maxLength="23"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textColor="#003366"
        android:textSize="@dimen/display_text_size"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>         

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Try to explain better what is happening or, even better, provide some images with the current and desired behavior.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have added the screenshot of the current image. The K cannot be shown properly. When wait for 5 second, then it automatically shows the full K but the figure on the right shifts rightwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `TableRow` inside a `TableLayout`. I think you can just use a horizontal `LinearLayout` instead. If you want to always maintain a space to show a symbol, give that view a fixed width instead of using `wrap_content`, otherwise it will grow/shrink when the content changes. (make sure to specify your width in dp units)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        android:layout_width="20dp" <!-- fixed size -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        <!-- more attributes -->
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" <!-- fill remaining space -->
        android:gravity="right"
        <!-- more attributes -->
    </TextView>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried but it is still looking the same. I set to even 500dp. The figure on the right shift much to the right, leave blank space on the left, that means the symbol editText occupies the space properly. Yet the K is still just showing half..

Comment: Which view did you try setting a fixed width for? I'm suggesting doing it for the "k". See my edit.

Comment: i have taken your above and further deleted android:layout_gravity="left" and then it is properly showing the full K instead of half K. Thanks for your help!!